# How to draw an arrow head in the globe projection

Tags: d3.js

I need to draw the arrow at end of the path, it worked fine in geoEquirectangular projection, but when I am using geoOrthographic projection and rotate it, the arrow disappeared.

This is how I created the arrow marker:

```
const markerBoxWidth = 10;
const markerBoxHeight = 10;
svg
    .append('defs')
    .append('marker')
    .attr('id', 'arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, markerBoxWidth, markerBoxHeight])
    .attr('refX', markerBoxWidth/2)
    .attr('refY', markerBoxHeight/2)
    .attr('markerWidth', markerBoxWidth)
    .attr('markerHeight', markerBoxHeight)
    .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.line()([[0, 0], [0, 10], [10, 5]]))
    .style('fill', 'green')
    .attr('stroke', 'green');
```

This is how to use it:

```
       svg.insert("path", ".graticule").datum(attacks).attr("class", "attacks")
        .attr('marker-start', 'url(#dotfrom)')
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)')
        .attr("d", path);
```

But the problem is if I am using this projection

```
var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
.scale(width / 2 - 10)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2])
.clipAngle(90)
.precision(.1);
```

and whenever the projection.rotate is called, the arrow disappeared.

I think this is mainly because the projection is not hooked up with the d3.line() method used in the marker definition. But I don't know how to use it. Can anyone give a suggestion here?

Thanks